# SVG (Raphaël) overlay with WebGL (THREE.js)

Tags: html, raphael, three.js, webgl

Currently I am using the THREE.js library to render a 3D scene, no issues there.

I would like to overlay an SVG , however I have the following issue, best demonstrated in image:

[image: Raphael Overlay]

As you can see, without WebGL (top image), my 2D Elements render. The red bar is from Raphael (SVG), and the grey thumbstick is rendered using pure Canvas 2D Context.

With WebGL underlayed (bottom image), the pure Canvas 2D Context continues to render normally, however the Raphael (SVG) takes on the appearance of the underlaying WebGL. The 3D View demonstrates that the layers and positions are correct however.

Is this simply a case of two incompatible methods of rendering, or is there perhaps a setting I might change somewhere. I would prefer to use Raphael for it's .onTouch functionality, but I am open to fall back to pure Canvas 2D Context for the overlay if I must.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a zIndex issue. When you add the three.js domelement what are you adding it to?

Is the svg higher up the dom tree and you append the webgl at the end?

Is the webgl absolutely positioned but the svg is not? etc